# Get data parameters with koala gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rubygems, koala

I send it the following parameters on my app request js:

```
= link_to_function _("Invite Friends to Blabloo"), 
              "FB.init({appId: '#{Facebook::APP_ID}', xfbml: true, cookie: true});FB.ui({  method: 'apprequests', 
                message: 'Invite Friends to Blabloo...',
                data: '{\"draw_token\":\"#{@draw.token}\",\"invitation_token\":\"#{current_kid.invitation_token}\"}',
                exclude_ids: #{@draw.get_invited_ids_for current_kid}},
                handle_fb_callback);", class: 'btn button btn-primary pull-right'
```

As you can see I'm send it two parameters:

> draw_token and invitation_token

Now, How can I get the values of those parameters on my index action of my home controller using Koala.

I getting a URL like this:

> https://apps.facebook.com/blabloo_pre/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=688449517881639&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_invite

I know that I have to get the request_ids using the params[:request_ids] but then I don't know what to do with koala and this value.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have idea how to call a simple facebook graph api, say `/me` using koala?

Comment: no, I new on this project

Comment: Haven't you used `@oauth= Koala::Facebook::OAuth.new(APP_ID, APP_SECRET,REDIRECT_URI)` anywhere? Used `access token` anywhere?